# how to reduce migrations of existing website that is developed in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration, reduce

I have 1000+ migrations of a website and tables are only 300-400, now i want to reduce the number of migrations without loosing any data is there any possibility to do it.

Comment: carefully, with lots of testing. And a backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 8 you'll be able to dump the database and throw away migrations thanks to [this PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/32275)

In the mean time, you can take a look at the PR code and implement it in your current version https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/32275/files.

The main idea is to use mysqldump (or pgdump, depending on your database) to dump your current database state and run a migration to import it.